# Why does my ASP.NET MVC form not post if the button type is a radio?

Tags: forms, asp.net-core-mvc, radio-button

I have a form that works perfectly and Posts data to controller Task xxxx

The code was auto-generated, so I am not worried if there are any errors somewhere else, since I didn't touch it except for adding the type.

In the view, I tried to add `type="radio"`, and placed a breakpoint on the controller function, but it was never triggered!

The first code can post and the breakpoint triggers, but the breakpoint never triggers on the second one"

```
        <div class="form-group form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" value="false" asp-for="US" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.US)
            </label>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input  type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="false" asp-for="US" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.US)
            </label>
        </div>
```

It's a weird problem; I just decided to use a radio button and after many hours tracing and debugging I got to this point... but how do I use radio buttons in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a form is posted, all fields will usually be posted, with checkboxes and radio buttons, if the input is not checked, the value will be posted. in your case, if there is no type maybe it's acting like a text or other input and sending an empty string, when setting to a radio button it's sending a null as the value. If your model is a boolean and it not nullable, this could be causing a binding issue and not completing.